# Posting to Kepware using Modbus Protocols

Tags: c++, modbus, opc, modbus-tcp

I am looking to send data into kepware using modbus. This is a completely new project my boss has given me and I am not sure where to start with my limited knowledge. Any insights on how this could be accomplished in C++ would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please explain the parts involved and the communication means between them (if you know that). For example, are you to write an OPC client code that communicates with KEPware OPC server which in turn talks Modbus to a device? Or is it something different?

Comment: Hey @ZbynekZ I appreciate the response. We are looking to write an OPC client code that can take in PLC data push it to a kepware server and then output to an ERP system (I think that is the end game) The example you gave seems to be about as close to what we are trying to do. We are in the manufacturing vertical so trying to grab data off a CNC machine (as an example) from the PLC and push through kepware to the ERP system

Comment: Kepware has a Modbus driver that can poll the PLC for you. There's no need to poll the data yourself and then push it into Kepware.

Comment: I am Green to all of this. Where would I get started to start manipulating kepWare and getting it to poll the data. We are also trying to create a hardware device that will monitor certain statistics off the machine itself using a pi2. We would essentially like to be able to intercept that data coming off the PLC look at the data and then send it into kepware. Is this also a possibility in addition to kepware doing it?

Comment: If you're not trying to manipulate that data in any way before it gets to Kepware, you're probably looking at this all wrong. The picture should look like this: Kepware connects to the PLC (that's what Kepware is really great at), and then you would connect to Kepware using an OPC-UA client to get at the data you're interested in.

Comment: ok so I think the question I should be asking is can I make a raspberry pi2 a kepware server and develop the OPC-UA on the pi as well to send the data out?

Comment: I don't think Kepware will run on a pi2, but you could certainly develop an OPC-UA cilent that would.

Comment: Ok perfect. Is there a way to intercept the PLC data and instead of it going to kepware, send it to somewhere else (let's say our cloud)?

Comment: I think you'd have to be the one polling the PLC yourself for that to happen. Conceivably, you could place your pi2 in the middle and configure Kepware to poll the pi2 as if it were a Modbus PLC. So: Kepware -> pi2 -> PLC, and when your pi2 received a Modbus poll from Kepware you send the same poll to the PLC, return the response to Kepware, and also do whatever you want with it (send to cloud, whatever). In that case you don't need to implement any OPC, but you'd have to implement both a Modbus client and server.

Comment: Do you know of any resources out there for wrappering data to send it to a kepware server via a modbus protocol? There is surprisingly little out there